# WiFi suddenly stopped working

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, intel

I have access to internet using a cable.
I have an HP Pavilion dv6 Notebook and I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:2e:5f:73:8c:9b  
          inet adr:192.168.2.29  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
          adr inet6: fe80::a2e:5fff:fe73:8c9b/64 Scope:Lien
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:15403 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12284 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
          Octets reçus:15442691 (15.4 MB) Octets transmis:1330124 (1.3 MB)

lo        Link encap:Boucle locale  
          inet adr:127.0.0.1  Masque:255.0.0.0
          adr inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Hôte
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:1402 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1402 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:0 
          Octets reçus:212762 (212.7 KB) Octets transmis:212762 (212.7 KB)


$ lspci -v | grep -i network -A 6
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 BGN
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at c2500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

[Here](http://www.overclock.net/t/1518258/solved-wireless-suddenly-stopped-working-in-ubuntu-14-04/10)
he seems to have a very similar problem and this command fixed it:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source && \
  sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

But I don't have a Broadcom... Is there a similar command I can execute?

Comment: Is `eth0:` in the ifconfig output, your wifi interface ? Are you sure you accidentally did not turn of the power to the wifi using a little slider switch that HP is famous for, placing in very inappropriate places ? If you checked all of these ans still can not make wifi function after a reboot, there is a likelihood that, the wifi adapter might have gone bad/broken

Comment: The wifi adapter is fine (it works on windows). The wifi switch is on my f12 key and their is a little light which is white when the wifi is on and orange when it's off. On windows, when pressing I can switch between those two states but on linux it's stuck on orange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, everything was soft blocked. The solution:

```
$ rfkill unblock all
```